# Why is my mixer circuit lowering the signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mixer, summing

I have made a really simple mixer, to be used with both audio and control signals in a modular system:
[image: Schematics, pots are also 10k linear]

This should if I understand it correctly give "about" 1:1 (1:0.99 in simulation) ratio beetween an input and the output. I've done a falstad simulation and there it looks "as it should" with a ratio of 1:0.99 which I think is close enough.
Link to simulation: [Falstad Mixer Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%203.7524723159601%2073%205%2050%0Aa%20288%20208%20432%20208%208%2015%20-15%201000000%200.000009900546278785291%200%20100000%0Aw%20288%20128%20288%20192%200%0Aw%20432%20208%20432%20128%200%0Ar%20288%20128%20432%20128%200%2010000%0Aw%20288%20224%20288%20272%200%0Ag%20288%20272%20288%20304%200%0Aw%20288%20192%20240%20192%200%0Aw%20240%20192%20240%20160%200%0Ar%20240%20160%20160%20160%200%2010000%0AR%2048%20128%200%20128%200%200%20200%201%200%200%200.159154943092%0AO%20640%20336%20704%20336%200%0Aa%20496%20224%20576%20224%208%2015%20-15%201000000%20-0.000009900348271819854%200%20100000%0Ar%20432%20208%20496%20208%200%2010000%0Ar%20496%20128%20560%20128%200%2010000%0Aw%20496%20128%20496%20208%200%0Aw%20560%20128%20576%20128%200%0Aw%20496%20240%20496%20272%200%0Aw%20496%20272%20288%20272%200%0Aw%20576%20128%20576%20224%200%0A174%20128%20128%20160%20192%201%2010000%200.005%20Resistance%0Aw%20288%20272%20176%20272%200%0Ac%20336%2048%20400%2048%200%202.7e-11%20-0.11348703878269256%0Ac%20496%2048%20576%2048%200%204.7e-11%20-0.9650194063654483%0Aw%20336%2064%20288%2064%200%0Aw%20288%2064%20288%20128%200%0Aw%20400%2064%20432%2064%200%0Aw%20432%2064%20432%20128%200%0Aw%20496%2064%20496%20128%200%0Aw%20576%2064%20576%20128%200%0A209%20576%20336%20640%20336%200%200.00001%208.466124468142766e-10%201%0Aw%20576%20256%20576%20224%200%0AO%20576%20224%20656%20224%200%0Aw%20128%20192%20128%20272%200%0Aw%20128%20272%20176%20272%200%0Ar%20576%20256%20576%20336%200%20100%0A368%20576%20224%20624%20176%200%200%0A368%20640%20336%20688%20288%200%200%0A368%20288%20192%20240%20224%200%200%0A368%20128%20128%20176%2080%200%200%0A368%20432%20208%20400%20240%200%200%0A368%20496%20208%20448%20304%200%200%0Aw%2048%20128%20128%20128%200%0Ao%209%2064%200%204098%202.5%200.025%200%202%209%203%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204098%201.25%200.00009765625%201%201%0A), the caps have been disconnected in the simulation. You can change the input from DC to AC to see how it would react on audio signals

But when I try it out IRL the signal is much lower (less than half) after going through the mixer than when bypassed, and that 1% in the ratio cant do that much can it? I did a test with adding 1v on the input and when I plugged it in it sank to 0.1v (about), the source was a nonbuffered voltage divider if that could be the reason for that? Also trying audio signals, less than half volume, and control signals half the range.

**The question: What am I missing?**

I'd appreciate any ideas on what to try next, and common errors that I might have missed. Thanks.

Comment: As you already mentioned, shouldn't your inputs be buffered. It seems you are overloading the input of your mixer.

Comment: In a simulator you probably put an ideal voltage source at the inputs, that means an output impedance of **zero** ohm. Now add a series resistor to that ideal voltage source with a realistic value of the output impedance of whatever drives this mixer. It could be that this impedance is more than a few kilo-ohms and then you easily get some signal loss.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. So the circuit works as it should and it is my input that is the problem then?

Comment: Or increase the input impedance of your mixer. The 10k pot in parallel with the 10k resistor gives just 5k, that's pretty low. Maybe make each one 47k or even 100k. You can't always control what's being plugged into it.

Comment: The other issue is that the input impedance will vary as you adjust the pot. At the minimum level it's 10k and at the maximum it's 5k. As you turn the level up, the source is loaded more and its output reduces. By making the pot significantly lower than the fixed mixing resistor you reduce this effect.

Comment: Is the VEE of the first opamp accidentally disconnected in the schematics only, or also on your real circuit?

Comment: @Justme It is a dual opamp so it is a miss in the schematics, pin 4 and 8 should only be on one opamp.

Comment: @Finbarr Thank you for all your input. Right now I am "forced" to use 10k pots, but you say to make the mixing resistor higher, do you mean R2 in the schematics above? significantly higher, as in 100k or even higher?

Comment: All the resistors connected to the - input of U1.2. 100k should be fine, that means the input impedance will only range from 10k to 9.09k

Comment: @Soucery no, not R2, changing it to 100k would make the total gain 10x. If that is your topology, i.e. can't change the schenatics, then you'd need larger than 10k pots. If you can add op-amps you can buffer each input first to drive the 10k pot so it does not load the source.

Comment: What is the source impedance of your signal sources? There are multiple comments about the low and variable input impedance of your mixer but this will only be an issue if the internal impedances of your signal sources are high enough (e.g. several kΩ).

Comment: At 27 pF C1 won't be an electrolytic, as shown in the diagram.

Comment: What are those pots? Are they fully up when you are measuring?

Comment: I'll answer the last comments here, @GrahamNye: ok, that is good to know. The signals will vary as it is a mixer, and different input signals will have different impedances, but the comment is useful as I can try a few different sound sources and see how they react. As for schematics, got it, I must have just chosen the wrong symbol. When transfered to PCB it hasnt polarity... Brian: I realized that the pots actually only have 20% tolerance, so that might be an issue too actually... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input impedances are too low, and they vary according to the input volume control. 5k is the load the input presents to the source at full volume. It should approximately be more like in the 50k range, perhaps 20k minimum.